DataGridView Editing in multiline mode
How do I make the DataGridView show multiline text when it is being edited?
I added:
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

That only shows multiline after editing is complete.

When the editing Control is about to be presented (EditingControlShowing), since it's a TextBox, you can set Multiline = true. But, the default implementation of the DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl may want to treat some of the cursor keys as input keys. You should then create your own DataGridViewTextBoxCell, replace the default DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl with your own implementation, so you can then override EditingControlWantsInputKey (which decides what keys should be sent to the DataGridView), to generate a different behavior

@Jimi, I believe that the Multiline property is already true as a consequence of setting WrapMode.

@IV. Nop.

WrapMode has nothing to do with the TextBox Control that is shown when you edit the Cell's content. What you see in a Cell in presentation mode is the graphic rendering of text

But I just tested it, guys. I have a Debug.Assert(textBox.Multiline) assert that either hits or not depending on whether I set dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True or not. Should I not believe my own lyin' eyes?

And @Jimi - I know you would be an authority on this - why wouldn't DGV already be adjusting the multiline height under the conditions of the OPs code during the editing phase of the cell? To me it feels like a bug that it wouldn't do this by default.

@IV. What I mean is that this is not relevant in this context. The altered behavior of the TextBox used as edit Control counts. If you need to override this behavior, the clean way is to generate a custom implementation (standard operation in this platform). See the EditingControlWantsInputKey method -- The Multiline feature is modified to just allow the TextBox to resize vertically. The input keys, as originally defined, remain the same

We might have a different understanding of the actual problem. What I noticed when I reproduced OPs bug is a multiline text box control that was working as expected, but was constrained in height by the Height property of the row that it's in. As a result, only one line of the multiline text is visible at a time, but the lines of text are actually present, and you can arrow up or down to scroll them.

Take it from here where the styles are applied to the editing control, which takes you to my first link. Do you see any access to the Multiline property? Should we not believe the source code?

@IV. We might have a different understanding of the actual problem: that's possible. The OP may want to explain in more details the context / design layout in which the issue appears

As I understand it, you'd like DataGridView to behave in the manner we're all accustomed to in MS Excel where you can see all of the lines of a multiline entry during editing, before commit and the row height adjustment that results.


What I reproduced from your code is that only the last line of a multiline entry is visible during editing, but appears normally after commit.


Here's one way that worked for me in testing. Ordinarily, the underlying cell value isn't changing when the text in the editing control does. The value is copied on a commit, and cancelling the operation simply skips the copy operation.
But by changing the underlying cell value in response to changes in the editor control, then the row height tracks because of the AutoSizeRows setting. If the edit is cancelled, however (e.g. the [Escape] key is pressed) it's now our responsibility to revert the cell value using the _revertText value that was pushed when the editor was shown.

Preconditions:

DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode is set to DataGridViewTriState.True
AutoSizeRowsMode is set to DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
[Shift][Enter] to add new line


public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Control is TextBox textBox)
            {
                Debug.Assert(textBox.Multiline, "Already true, and this is due to WrapMode property setting");
                _revertText = textBox.Text;
                textBox.TextChanged -= localOnTextChanged;
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= localPreviewKeyDown;
                textBox.TextChanged += localOnTextChanged;
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown += localPreviewKeyDown;

                void localOnTextChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(() => // Because drawing artifacts have been known to occur otherwise.
                    {
                        dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = textBox.Text;
                    });
                }
                void localPreviewKeyDown(object? sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
                {
                    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
                    {
                        dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = _revertText;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        dataGridView.CellValidating += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(
                $"Ensure that, regardless, only one cell validation happens per commit {dataGridView.CurrentCell?.Value}");
        };
        Records.Add(new Record());
    }
    string _revertText = string.Empty;
    BindingList<Record> Records = new BindingList<Record>();
}
class Record
{
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

